# SQL Contains() with a single word does not return all expected rows

Tags: sql-server, contains

I am running a simple SQL contains search and the result does not include all expected rows.

All I need is a search that works in the same way as LIKE %word%.

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] where contains(Name, N'walmart')
```

By running this select, the rows returned seem to only contains name with "walmart" with either space before or after or some kind of other delimiter like a period ("walmart.com"). No problem here.

But one row was not returned and its value is "mywalmart". Why does this row fail to return with the contains search? If I use `name LIKE '%walmart%'` it works just fine.

What do I need to fix the contains search to make it work?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-wildcards

Comment: @PM77-1 Good reference, but it specifically says the wildcard cannot be used in front of the word for suffix-matching.

Answer (score 2):

Contains doesn't work the way you think, for your purposes LIKE is best.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on this:

CONTAINS can search for:

- A word or phrase.
- The **prefix** of a word or phrase.
- A word near another word.
- A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
- A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and "steel").